# Where (if any) is the best place to submit feedback about the BQ Aquarius Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, bq, aquaris

I thought I'd buy the Aquarius to play around with Ubuntu Touch.
I know it's a work in progress but a very good start.
If I notice any bugs or would like to submit any other feedback, where should I go/email?

Comment: Two places I can think of: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-phone and https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone-coreapps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually an app called"feedback" that you can download from the store. BQ always come back to me with feedback after I post something there.

In addition, you can also email bq directly at support.ubuntu.en@bq.com

Comment: I just went to the store from the phone and can't find any feedback app. I searched for 'feedback' and got 8 hits, none of them what you describe

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu and Canonical provides many methods to be in contact with. Pleas refer to this http://www.ubuntu.com/about/contact-us.

I think also you can find some launchpad related to Ubuntu touch:https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-touch-preview

Moreover if there is something in hardware you should contact the BQ company:http://www.bq.com/gb/support/aquaris-e4-5-ubuntu-edition